# convert sub-arrays with only one value to a string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, the sub-arrays consist of further values, I would like for all sub-arrays that only have one value to be converted into a string. How can I successfully scan through a multidimensional array to get the result?

Below is a small section of the array as it is now.

```
[1] => Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Person's name
        )

    [organisation] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is their organisation
            [1] => aka something else
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => The street name
            [1] => The town name
        )

    [e-mail] => Array
        (
            [0] => test@this.site.com
        )

)
```

and here is how I would like it to end up

```
[1] => Array
(
    [name] =>  Person's name

    [organisation] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is their organisation
            [1] => aka something else
        )

    [address] => Array
        (
            [0] => The street name
            [1] => The town name
        )

    [e-mail] => test@this.site.com

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work no matter how deep the array is.

Put this function in your code:

```
function array2string(&$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        if(count($v, COUNT_RECURSIVE) == 1){
            $v = $v[0];
            return;
        }
        array_walk($v, 'array2string');
    }
}
```

Then do this:

```
array_walk($array, 'array2string');
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
function array2string(&$v){
    if(is_array($v) && count($v)==1){
        $v = $v[0];
    }
}
array_walk($array, 'array2string');
```

Or as a one-liner, since I'm nuts.

```
array_walk($array, create_function('&$v', 'if(is_array($v) && count($v)==1){$v = $v[0];}'));
```

**EDIT**: It looks like that array is an element in a bigger array.  You need to put this function inside of a foreach loop.

```
function array2string(&$v){
    if(is_array($v) && count($v)==1){
        $v = $v[0];
    }
}
foreach($array as &$val){
    array_walk($val, 'array2string');
}
```

Or using my crazy `create_function` one-liner.

```
foreach($array as &$val){
    array_walk($val, create_function('&$v', 'if(is_array($v) && count($v)==1){$v = $v[0];}'));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the resulting array looks as if it hasn't changed, even the single items still are set as arrays.

Comment: Try looping through the array, and using the `array_walk` on each element.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it.  The `foreach($array as $val)` needs to be `foreach($array as &$val)`.

Comment: That seems to work with the first few levels, the array I'm currently working with is five levels deep and doesn't work after the third level

Comment: Seems I can't use `array_walk` for this, gotta do it manually.

Comment: So for an array 10 levels deep, i have to place 10 nested for-loops to resolve the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I didn't realize the array was more than 2 levels deep.  I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This PHP 5.3 code uses a closure. You can use a named function, too, if you want. It specifically checks for strings, and calls itself for nested arrays.

```
<?php
array_walk($array, $walker = function (&$value, $key) use (&$walker) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        if (count($value) === 1 && is_string($value[0])) {
            $value = $value[0];
        } else {
            array_walk($value, $walker);
        }       
    }   
});
```