# SimpleDB results into PHP array format

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, amazon-simpledb

I know variations of this question have been asked and answered before, but I'm a smart guy and after literally weeks of searching off and on, I cannot find what I need.  There must be some easy way to do this I am missing.

Existing code:

```
$response = $sdb->get_attributes('domain','itemname');
$newresponse = $response->body->GetAttributesResult->to_array();
print_r($newresponse);
```

I get this result:

```
CFArray Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [Attribute] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => tenants
                            [Value] => Sam Smith
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => tenants
                            [Value] => Janet Jones
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => tenants
                            [Value] => Willy Wonka
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [Name] => buildingName
                            [Value] => 123 Main St.
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What I want this data to look like:

```
Array
(
   [tenants] => Array
      (
         [0] => Sam Smith
         [1] => Janet Jones
         [2] => Willy Wonka
      )

   [buildingName] => 123 Main St.
)
```

I need to account for `[tenants]` having one or more values. The other variables may or may not have a single value.  I also must account for the possibility that the `[tenants]` may not be in sequential order (i.e. `[buildingName]` was `[2]` and another `[tenants]` was in `[3]`.  There's clearly a concept here I do not understand.  How do I do this?

**EDIT to address private array comment**
If I modify the existing code to the following:

```
$response = $sdb->get_attributes('domain','itemname');
$newresponse = $response->body->GetAttributesResult->to_array()->getArrayCopy();
print_r($newresponse);
```

I get this result:

```
Array
(
    [Attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => tenants
                    [Value] => Sam Smith
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => tenants
                    [Value] => Janet Jones
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => tenants
                    [Value] => Willy Wonka
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => companyname
                    [Value] => 123 Main St.
                )

        )

)
```

So while reference to 'private' is gone, the same basic question applies.

**FINAL SOLUTION based on user2057272's answer**

user2053727, you are both a gentleman (or gentlewoman) and a scholar.  Your answer worked *almost* perfectly.  The one issue I had was that the result was:

```
Array
(
    [tenants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sam Smith
            [1] => Janet Jones
            [2] => Willy Wonka
        )

    [buildingName] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123 Main St.
        )
)
```

To fix the `[buildingName]` to be a string instead of an array (because there is only one element), I modified my final code to the following:

```
$response= $sdb->get_attributes('domain','itemname');
$newresponse = $response->body->GetAttributesResult->to_array();
$new = array();  
foreach($newresponse["Attribute"] as $key => $value) 
    {  
    if(!isset($new[$value['Name']])) 
        {  
        $new[$value['Name']] = array();  
        }  
    $new[$value['Name']][] = $value['Value'];  
    }
array_walk($new, $walker = function (&$value, $key) use (&$walker) 
    {
    if (is_array($value)) 
        {
        if (count($value) === 1 && is_string($value[0])) 
            {
            $value = $value[0];
            }
        else 
            {
            array_walk($value, $walker);
            }       
         }   
    }
    );
print_r($new);
```

My gratitude to janmoesen ([convert sub-arrays with only one value to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569734/convert-sub-arrays-with-only-one-value-to-a-string)) with the `array_walk` part.

My result is now exactly what I need:

```
Array
(
    [tenants] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sam Smith
            [1] => Janet Jones
            [2] => Willy Wonka
        )

    [buildingName] => 123 Main St.
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: user2053727, I don't know what that means (and Google is not helpful). However I found that if I add `->getArrayCopy()` after the `->to_array()` on the `$newresults` line that it eliminates the private stuff and the first key in the array becomes `[Attribute]`. So I still have the same problem as described above.

Comment: you should post the [Attribute] output to make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new = array();  
foreach($newresponse["Attribute"] as $key => $value) {  
    if(!isset($new[$value['Name']])) {  
        $new[$value['Name']] = array();  
    }  
    $new[$value['Name']][] = $value['Value'];  
}  
var_dump($new)
```

customize as you need.

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed.  Thank you.  I edited my original question to post my final solution above.